# How to query subscription to an array field in postgresql/sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

My data consists of books that can be assigned multiple categories (horror, drama, comedy, etc).  Users can subscribe to a category and I want to be able to perform paginated queries to the books table for all books that have a specified category.  Example schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books (
  bookid uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  categories uuid[],
  name text,
  author text,
  releasedate timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (
  categoryid uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  name text
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  userid uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  name text
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS catsubscribers (
  categoryid uuid REFERENCES categories,
  userid uuid REFERENCES users,
  PRIMARY KEY (categoryid,  userid)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST bookcats (
  bookid uuid REFERENCES books,
  categoryid uuid REFERENCES categories,
  PRIMARY KEY (bookid, categoryid)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getBooksBySubscribedCategory(me uuid, ofst integer, lim integer)
RETURNS TABLE(bookid uuid, categories uuid[], name text, author text, releasedate timestamp) AS $$
  DECLARE cid RECORD;
  BEGIN
    FOR cid IN (SELECT categoryid FROM catsubscribers WHERE userid = me)
    LOOP
      RETURN QUERY SELECT bks.bookid, bks.categories, bks.name, bks.author, bks.releasedate
      FROM (SELECT bookid, categories, name, author, releasedate FROM books WHERE bookid IN (SELECT bookid FROM bookcats WHERE categoryid = cid ) AS bks
      ORDER BY releasedate DESC
      OFFSET ofst
      LIMIT lim;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This function gets the array of categories a user is subscribed to, and loops over each category and queries for books in the bookcats junction table.  This is my brute force first attempt -- its ugly, and I'm not sure if even gets pagination correct because of the loop.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need looping at all,

```
RETURN QUERY 
SELECT bks.bookid, bks.categories, bks.name, bks.author, bks.releasedate
from books bks join bookcats bc on bc.bookid = bks.bookid
join catsubscribers cs on cs.categoryid = bc.categoryid
where cs.userid = me 
group by bks.bookid, bks.categories, bks.name, bks.author, bks.releasedate
limit lim offset ofst
```

Comment: I thought there might be a 'intersection' type option, but I think the multiple join will have better performance?

Comment: Yes multiple joins are just fine, just make sure you have set them as Foreign keys and if the data set is large indexing them will improve the performance even further.

Answer (score 1):

`OFFSET` and `LIMIT` is the classic choice, but there are other considerations that can come up when you have performance issues: https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way and https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page is a good overview of how to implement a performant pagination.

The upshot is to maintain the page state needed externally and instead of offset/limit, use a `WHERE` filter to just grab the relevant rows directly by filtering (in this case) on `releasedate` before the current page and limiting it to the page size.